# Allure report shows 404 error within report although the history captures the correct data

Tags: python, python-2.7, automated-tests, pytest, allure

I fire off my test and generate the XML like so:

```
pytest LoginTest.py --alluredir C:\Users\jfriend\Desktop\Allure\xml
```

So I have a directory which is in the path above, which has XMLs / txt files. Which is fine.

I want to now generate a report along side serving the report. Looking at the docs it looks like I have to do something like:

```
allure generate C:/Users/jfriend/Desktop/Allure/xml
```

This should generate a report in the directory I currently am within the CLI. It should grab the results generated from pytest with the adaptor from the above path.

Instead it will generate a report, but it will only display a 404 Error within the middle of the page. Which is strange.

If I read the history, it has the correct data - so it has clearly read the XML directory. And if I run the serve command like so:

```
allure serve C:\Users\jfriend\Desktop\Allure\xml
```

It displays the tests correctly. So it can clearly see the results and can display them, but it just refuses to generate it for some reason.

Any ideas? I just want to have the static report along side with the server report purely for archive reasons.

Comment: You need to have a web server to view the report due to security issues. So when you are using `allure generate` command it will generate the report to `allure-report` folder. Then to view the report use `allure open` command (`allure serve` is shortcut for `allure generate -o /tmp/some/folder & allure open /tmp/some/folder`)

Comment: @DmitryBaev Oh right, Thought double clicking the index would suffice. What security issues?

Comment: Allure Report is SPA, that uses AJAX to get page content. Chrome prevents access to files on file system (such check can be disabled via --allow-file-access-from-files option)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allure Report is SPA, that uses AJAX to get page content. Chrome prevents access to files on file system (such check can be disabled via `--allow-file-access-from-files` option).

So you need to serve report using web server to view it. Allure command line has `open` command that will start Jetty for you.

PS

`allure serve` command is shortcut for `allure generate && allure open`.